# Returning count of associations instead of all associations themselves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

So, an `Object` has many `properties` and a `property` belongs to an `Object`. That's currently the association. Now when I render all the objects, using Object.all and include the `:properties` associations, I get all the attributes of the `property` model in the rendered JSON. But I really don't need that. All I need is the **number** of associations there are. I.e., just the number of properties there are associated with any one object. Here is my code:

```
@objects = Object.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { 
    render json: @objects.to_json(:include => [:properties]) 
  }
end
```

This yields something like this. There is currently only 1 `property` associated with the 1 existing `object`, and as you can see in the JSON, I'm getting a lot of information about the associated `properties`, (or rather, property) that I don't need nor want.

```
"id": 2,
"attrs_go_here": "asdfsdaf"
"created_at": "2018-07-14T23:51:55.161Z",
"updated_at": "2018-07-14T23:51:55.161Z",
"properties": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "more_attributes": "asdfasdfasdf"
        "created_at": "2018-07-14T23:53:14.917Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-07-14T23:53:14.917Z"
     }
]
```

But instead, I want something like this, where I get the number of associations:

```
"id": 2,
"attrs_go_here": "asdfsdaf"
"created_at": "2018-07-14T23:51:55.161Z",
"updated_at": "2018-07-14T23:51:55.161Z",
"properties": 1
```

My reasoning for only wanting the number is because there could potentially be hundreds of thousands of properties associated with any one object. And I feel like it would be really slow to render ALL the attributes of ALL the properties associated with an object when all I need is the number of associations there are between an object and its properties in the first place.

Comment: can you add the schema for the properties table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a method to you model `Object`

```
def properties_count
  self.properties.count
end
```

And on you controller do

```
render json: @objects.to_json(methods: [:properties_count])
```

Although I am not sure about a possible n+1. In case of that you should use

```
@objects = Object.includes(:properties).all
```

Edit
Technically its not intended to give arguments `to_json` only takes getters. But you could do something along those lines:

```
class Object
  attr_accessor :attribute

  def method_with_params(attribute = nil)
    attribute ||= attribute
    # rest of your code
  end
end


@object.attribute = 'foodbar'
render json: @object.to_json(methods: [:method_with_params]
```

)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much that worked! An additional question: How could you do the same thing (entering the methods in the `to_json` method) if one of the methods takes in parameters? For instance: `@objects.to_json(methods: [:properties_count, :method_with_params(args)])` This of course is not correct.. It throws a syntax error. I was just wondering if it was possible. Even if not, you solved my problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This answer will replace "properties" with "properties_count" for simplicity

```
Object.select('objects.*', 'COUNT(properties.id) as properties_count')
      .joins(:properties)
      .group('objects.id')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that states: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "properties` Should I run a migration to add `properties` to the `object` model? That's the only thing I can think of doing with this error, but doing so would defeat the whole point of the association. Plus, would data type would you use to add a column that holds a collection?? I'm a little confused.